# CorePlot errors after upgrading to xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

I updated xcode today to version 7.3 and suddenly the module using CorePlot is throwing errors.  "graph in unavailable" and "dataSource is unavailable".  I have not made changes to this section of code since inception.  I noticed that there is a new version of CorePlot - will that help or hurt?
Code snippet:

```
//1a - set up the 2 scatter plots - avg expected return for each portfolio
CPTScatterPlot *modelAvgRtnPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
modelAvgRtnPlot.dataSource = self;
modelAvgRtnPlot.identifier = @"Portfolio A Expected Avg Return";
modelAvgRtnPlot.title = @"Model (A) Average Rtn";
```

The `modelAvgRtnPlot.dataSource = self;` line gives the compile error 'dataSource in unavailable'

second issue with 'graph' - snippet:

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
// 1 - Is the plot hidden?
if (plot.isHidden == YES) {
    return;
}
// 2 - Create style, if necessary
static CPTMutableTextStyle *style = nil;
if (!style) {
    style = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    style.color= [CPTColor darkGrayColor];
    style.fontSize = 16.0f;
    style.fontName = @"Raleway-Bold";
}
// 3 - Create annotation, if necessary
NSNumber *price = [self numberForPlot:plot      field:CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip recordIndex:index];
if (self.priceDeviationAnnotation) {
    [plot.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:self.priceDeviationAnnotation];
    self.priceDeviationAnnotation = nil;
}
```

in the above, `[plot.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea...]` is giving the error "'graph' is unavailable"

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a another solution:**

i have fixed this issue, Xcode - **BuildSetting** - **Weak Reference in Manual Retain Release** to **Yes** and solved.

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling your project without ARC enabled? There was some recent discussion in [this github issue](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/269) about projects compiled without ARC failing with Xcode 7.3.  It has been fixed in the master branch with [this commit](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/commit/272db3d17bc062cbd5c2de5dffe6747224b6ffb4).

If you're unable to upgrade to master at this time, removing `cpt_weak` from the property definitions that are giving you problems should fix your compilation error.

Comment: Removing the cpt_weak did it for me.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3277209 you're welcome.  Would you mind accepting the answer?